# Where can I obtain the software called “Instructor”?

Tags: software, instructions

The instructions on [JK Brickworks](http://jkbrickworks.com/instructions/) state (boldface mine):

> Publishing was done using **Instructor version 1.6**

However, if I search the Internet, the only pertinent results are the aforementioned instructions and the creator of that site does not provide any means to contact him to ask.

Where can I learn more about this software or obtain it? Is it known under another name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An older version (1.4) of Instructor is advertised in [this forum post](http://forums.ldraw.org/thread-7730-post-7730.html?highlight=instructor#pid7730) and can be downloaded [here](http://truedimensions.com/lego/instructor/build/instructor14_394.zip).

As you can see on [the Google+ post](http://plus.google.com/+TruedimensionsArt/posts/8YZL3U5ezYm), the differences between 1.4 and 1.6 are mostly cosmetic.

Answer (score 3):

It seems Instructor is actually being developed by JK Brickworks themselves, according to [this Google+ post](http://plus.google.com/+TruedimensionsArt/posts/8YZL3U5ezYm). Your best option would be asking them directly, as there is no download link on their website.

Comment: *Your best option would be asking them directly* – Sadly, I fail to find any contact information …

Comment: If you're on Facebook you can send them a message.  https://www.facebook.com/JKBrickworks/